# Find Measure of Angle $E$

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

How do you solve for angle $YEP$

I have tried using $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\tan$ to solve but I can't.
Is there supposed to be a rule of $30,60,90$ triangle when the altitude is made?

Comment: Please post image here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In triangle $AEP$ , $AE=$$20\over {\cos A}$ In the big triangle, $AE=25\cos A$

Equating them, you get $\cos A = $$2\over {\sqrt{5}}$ .

Angle $YEP$ = $90^o - $angle $PEA$ = angle $A$